# Understanding the Proof of a Theorem 1.9 and Theorem 2.5 from Chartrand's Graphs and Digraphs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, proof-explanation

There are two Theorems in Chartrand's Graphs and Digraphs that follow the same line of argument and arrive at an inequality that I can't seem to understand where it is deduced from. The inequality being the following: $(deg(u)-1) + (deg(v)-1) \leq n-2$ and $deg(u) + deg(v) \leq n-2$ in Theorem $1.9$ and Theorem $2.5$ respectively.

The two Theorems are shown below:

---

[image]

[image]

---

Both proofs follow the same line of logic. I understand the proofs, however, how can we be certain that the sum of the degrees of vertices is always less than $(n-2)$?

For example, the deletion of $1$ from $deg(u)$ and $deg(v)$, respectively, from the LHS of the inequality: $(deg(u)-1) + (deg(v)-1) \leq n-2$ comes from there being no vertex $w$ adjacent to both vertex $u$ and $v$ (since the new graph does not contain a triangle), is that correct? Furthermore, how is it bounded above by $(n-2)$?

Also, in Theorem $2.5$, is it (implicitly) following a proof by contracdition method? Since it isn't stated, however comes to a contradiction.

Comment: I believe that by subtracting 1 from deg u and deg v, we are accounting for the 1 edge we know to be adjacent to those vertices, namely the one connecting them. We are counting how many *other* vertices are adjacent to those 2 vertices, and observing that if this number is too large, then among the n-2 remaining vertices, there must be one (by the pigeonhole principle) adjacent to both u and v. Taking the contrapositive of this implication gives the desired inequality (I think).

Answer (score 1):

Let $N_x$ denote the neighbourhood of vertex $x$ so that:
$$
N_x = \{y \in V(G) \mid xy \in E(G)\}
$$

---

For the inequality from Theorem 1.9, observe that $N_u \cap N_v = \varnothing$ (otherwise, if there was some $w \in N_u \cap N_v$, then $u \to w \to v \to u$ would be a triangle). Hence, observe that:
\begin{align*}
n
&=|V(G)| \\
&\geq |\{u\} \cup \{v\} \cup N_u \cup N_v| \\
&= |N_u \cup N_v| &\text{since $u \in N_v$ and $v \in N_u$} \\
&= |N_u| + |N_v| &\text{since $N_u \cap N_v = \varnothing$} \\
&= \deg u + \deg v\\
\end{align*}

---

Likewise, for the inequality from Theorem 2.5, observe that $N_u \cap N_v = \varnothing$ (otherwise, if there was some $w \in N_u \cap N_v$, then $u \to w \to v$ would be a $(u, v)$-path). Hence, observe that:
\begin{align*}
n
&=|V(G)| \\
&\geq |\{u\} \cup \{v\} \cup N_u \cup N_v| \\
&= |\{u\}| + |\{v\}| + |N_u| + |N_v| &\text{since all four sets are pairwise disjoint} \\
&= 2 + \deg u + \deg v\\
\end{align*}